# python , pandas , numpy ,replace function not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, replace

```python
median1=df["Partner_salary"].median()

df[(df['Partner_working']=='Yes')&(df['Partner_salary'].isnull())].replace(np.nan,median1, inplace =True)
```

Here I want to replace the NaN values only in case of working partner else I want the NaN value to be 0.0

Why is `inplace=True` not working and I am getting the same amount of null values again?

Comment: Why not use [`.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html)?

Comment: how to do that if we have two conditions

Comment: I think I misunderstood your point, sorry: The funny thing is that a Pandas inplace-operation on a view (your `df[...]`) makes a copy out of the view (at least my experiments indicate it), and the results aren't propagated back to the original object. That's another inplace-bummer. Don't use it.

Comment: You could do `df.loc[df["partner_working"].eq("Yes") & df["partner_salary"].isnull(), "partner_salary"] = median1` instead.